# How come my 11.10 3D does not work even though my graphics card is supported?

Tags: 11.10, ati

> OpenGL vendor string:   X.Org R300 Project
>
> OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS690
>
> OpenGL version string:  1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.11)
>
> Not software rendered:    yes
>
> Not blacklisted:          yes
>
> GLX fbconfig:             yes
>
> GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
>
> GL npot or rect textures: yes
>
> GL vertex program:        yes
>
> GL fragment program:      yes
>
> GL vertex buffer object:  no
>
> GL framebuffer object:    yes
>
> GL version is 1.4+:       yes
>
> Unity 3D supported:       no

---

So Unity 3D is not supported because of... "GL vertex buffer"? Am I understanding that right?

Even though I've been with Ubuntu since 8.10, I'm still quite the n00b, so any help would be great! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, verify you have the video driver installed. You need to have the ati proprietary driver for 3d acceleration otherwise it treats it as a standard integrated card without 3D. The reason for that is it doesn't have the ability to access the card entirely.

> sudo apt-get install fglrx